# How to streamline multiple Javascript IF statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I have the following JS which is intended to run this statement:
"If the URL for the current page contains `STRING1` then toggle the checkbox for the ID: `TOPIC1`"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("STRING1") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("TOPIC1").checked = true;
  }
});
```

I have 15 Topics in a list and I would like to optimize the code to substitute `STRING1` and `TOPIC1` for each of the different topics.

Someone suggested that I use javascript switch statements but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Here's a switch statement I came up with...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  switch (window.location.href.indexOf("free") > -1){
    case "STRING1":
      document.getElementById("TOPIC1").checked = true;
      break;
    case "STRING2":
      document.getElementById("TOPIC2").checked = true;
      break;
    case "STRING3":
      document.getElementById("TOPIC3").checked = true;
      break;
    case "STRING4":
      document.getElementById("TOPIC4").checked = true;
      break;
  }
});
```

Unfortunately that ⬆︎ doesn't work. Any help would be really appreciated!

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jord8on/gfsxqkf7/)

Comment: If they are always called as `STRINGx` and `TOPICx` where `x` always matches, then you don't need `if` conditions at all - you can just parse this number `x` and get element by `getElementById("TOPIC" + x)`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I think it's safe to assume that they are not called "STRINGx" and "TOPICx".

Comment: @JLRishe Yes, I guess. I just present the idea, whatever they are called, the OP still can parse `x` from it if it always contains this `x` instead of writing mapping dictionary \ switch \ if etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're `switch`ing over something that's either `true` or `false`.

I would avoid `switch` - it's longer than necessary and can easily cause problems when you forget a `break`. When you can, use object lookup instead:

```
const stringsToIds = [
  ['STRING1', 'TOPIC1'],
  ['STRING2', 'TOPIC2'],
  ['STRING3', 'TOPIC3'],
];
const { href } = window.location;
const match = stringsToIds.find(([str]) => href.includes(str));
if (match) document.getElementById(match[1]).checked = true;
```

That way, your code is very terse and easy to make sense of.

Comment: This was the cleanest and most streamlined bit of code, from the solutions offered. It was perfect for my needs. Thanks for the explanation and recommendation re: `switch` Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var pairs = [
         { match: "STRING1", check: "TOPIC1" },
         { match: "STRING2", check: "TOPIC2" },
         { match: "STRING3", check: "TOPIC3" }
    ];

    var foundPair = pairs.find(function (pair) {
        return window.location.href.indexOf(pair.match) > -1;
    });

    if (foundPair) {
        document.getElementById(foundPair.check).checked = true;
    }
});
```

Note that `Array#find` is not supported by default in IE but can be added by use of a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an object. Something like this,

```
var strToID = {
  "STRING1": () => {
    document.getElementById("TOPIC1").checked = true;
  },
  "STRING2": () => {
    document.getElementById("TOPIC2").checked = true;
  }
}
if(window.location.href.indexOf("STRING1") > -1 && strToID["STRING1"]) {
  strToID["STRING1"]();
}
```